# Disable Ubuntu 22.04's scaning processes / candidates after package upgrades

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

Ubuntu 22.04 scans running processes (for use of old libraries) after doing apt. It will say 'Scanning processes' and 'Scanning candidates':

[image]

We have servers that (unfortunately) need to run tens of thousands of processes. On those servers, this process takes about 5 hours.

I understand the reasons why it's done, but can it be disabled? So far I don't see an apt or systemd setting.

The process taking all CPU is `systemd`, or `/sbin/init` (PID 1).

Answer (score 5):

I found it. I saw `apt-pinvoke` as running process, which comes from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99needrestart`. I disabled the line in it.